# Count the # of times a specific value occurs in one column per unique identifier in another column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with two columns.

Col1 is unique company ID's. These ID's occur multiple times, representing each time a company was quoted.

Col2 is a description of the work performed for the company. 'Attempted', 'Invoiced', 'Cancelled', etc.

I need to count the number of times per company ID (Col1) 'Attempted' occurs in Col2. This will be Col 3.

ex. What I have:

```
Company ID   Work Described
COM123A      Attempted
COM123A      Invoiced
COM789B      Invoiced
COM123A      Attempted
```

ex. What I want:

```
Company ID   Work Described       # of 'Attempted'
COM123A      Attempted                     2              
COM123A      Invoiced                      2
COM789B      Invoiced                      0
COM123A      Attempted                     2
```

This is what I have tried so far. I start by making a new dataframe.

```
jobAttemptedDF = pd.DataFrame()
jobAttemptedDF = df['Col2'].eq('Attempted').groupby(df['Col1']).count().astype(int).reset_index(name='Col3')
```

But the results are off.

How can I count the number of times 'Attempted' occurs in Col2 per unique identifier in Col1?

Answer (score 3):

Very close, we want `'sum'` here not `'count'`.

`count` will give the number of non-`NaN` values in the group. We want to tally the number of `True` values that were created by the comparison operation of `df['Work Described'].eq('Attempted')`.

Since `True` is `1` and `False` is `0` for mathematical operations, `sum` does a good job of tallying the number of `True` values.:

```
df['# of Attempted'] = (
    df['Work Described'].eq('Attempted')
        .groupby(df['Company ID']).transform('sum')
)
```

`df`:

|  | Company ID | Work Described | # of Attempted |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | COM123A | Attempted | 2 |
| 1 | COM123A | Invoiced | 2 |
| 2 | COM789B | Invoiced | 0 |
| 3 | COM123A | Attempted | 2 |

*[`groupby transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.transform.html) is also helpful here as it allows a new column to easily be added back to the DataFrame.

---

Setup:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Company ID': ['COM123A', 'COM123A', 'COM789B', 'COM123A'],
    'Work Described': ['Attempted', 'Invoiced', 'Invoiced', 'Attempted']
})
```